# Get gender of invitable_friends in Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing a Facebook application for ladies out there where users can only send invites to other females.

Is it possible to find out the gender from `invitable_friends` list (or any other way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no gender field in the result of `invitable_friends`, and the ids you get back are not realy ids but invite tokens only.

So there is no way to get the gender of friends afaik. Except for friends who authorized your App too. In that case, you can use `me/friends?fields=name,gender`.

Comment: That's what I feared. I was looking if there was any way around. Maybe multiple calls to get the end-result. Didn't get much help on google as well.

Comment: no, since you don´t get user ids but only invite tokens, additional calls will not help either. there´s no way, i am afraid.